# Display success/Failure count in Swing Dialog box in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

[image]   How to get the assertion result in JSR2233 Sampler or Beanshell Sampler,so that it would be helpful to show the total number of test case ,success test case ,failure test case in swing showMessageDialog, once testcase execution completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure if I have understood question correctly!

You seem to be using JMeter for functional testing which is fine! I assume that each request (or Sampler) is a test case. If the below answer is not really you were looking for, provide more info.

**setUp Thread Group**:

I create these 2 variables in a Beanshell Sampler.

```
bsh.shared.success = 0;
bsh.shared.fail = 0;
```

**Thread Group:**

I add the below code to update success / fail count based on the assertion result in a `Beanshell Listener`.

```
if(sampleResult.isSuccessful()){
    bsh.shared.success++;
}else{
    bsh.shared.fail++;
}
```

**tearDown Thread Group**:

I finally display the Success and failed testcases count. You can use your Swing method here!

```
log.info("PASSED : " + bsh.shared.success);
log.info("FAILED : " + bsh.shared.fail);
```

[image]

Comment: ,This is perfectly matching my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but you're violating 2 main rules of JMeter Best Practices:

1. [Run tests in non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui). Use GUI for tests development and debugging only.
2. [Use the most performing scripting language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

When you run your tests in command-line non-GUI mode you can get interim and final statistics via [Summariser](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/reporters/Summariser.html) which is enabled by default:

[image: Summarizer Stats]

See [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/nine-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide for more detailed explanation of above recommendations and other JMeter performance and tuning tips and tweaks.

Comment: @Dimitri  I would like to shows  the test case execution result once it is completed, so i prefer Swing ShowmessageDialog box.yes thanks for your input, i will try to do the execution via command prompt.